# Draw diagonal line from top right corner to bottom left using nested for loop in c# console app

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, for-loop

I have matrix 5x5 filled with zeroe.

I'm going to draw diagonal line from top right corner to bottom left corner using nested for loop.

**expected output** :

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

**my output**:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

my code so far:

```
using System;

namespace practice_04
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array = new int[5, 5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = (i == j) ? 1 : 0;

                Console.Write($"{array[i, j]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't get it how to reverse my output into expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slight modification will do the trick:

```
array[i, j] = (i == 4 - j) ? 1 : 0;
```

For better code quality I'd suggest using array sizes further down the code after initializing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
```

and

```
array[i, j] = (i == array.GetLength(0) - 1 - j) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You print your array like this:

```
i\j 0 1 2 3 4
 0  0 0 0 0 1
 1  0 0 0 1 0
 2  0 0 1 0 0
 3  0 1 0 0 0
 4  1 0 0 0 0
```

Therefore you want `i + j == 4` instead of `i == j`

This is how `i+j` looks like, if you're not convinced yet:

```
i\j 0 1 2 3 4
 0  0 1 2 3 4
 1  1 2 3 4 5
 2  2 3 4 5 6
 3  3 4 5 6 7
 4  4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

A Little Mistake in the for loop. Attached the correct Line:

```
for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
{
    array[i, j] = (i == j) ? 1 : 0;

    Console.Write($"{array[i, j]} ");
}
```

Then your output will be mirrored:

```
i\j 4 3 2 1 0
 0  0 0 0 0 1
 1  0 0 0 1 0
 2  0 0 1 0 0
 3  0 1 0 0 0
 4  1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I edited your answer to add why it works. Feel free to rollback if you prefer your own version :)